# Convert primary partition to logical partition in linux

Tags: linux, partition, gparted

I have created new partition through Gparted in linux mint and now have used up all 4 primary partitions. Gparted directly created primary partition, the logical option was disabled.
 So I cannot create any more partitions even though there is lot of free space on my disk.

How can I convert the data partition(non system related) to a logical partition, so that it frees up a primary one?
I would prefer a Linux solution, since I have recently switched to Mint 19.1 from Windows 10 though it is still present as dual boot.

**Output of sfdisk:**

```
sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda
label: dos
label-id: 0xfc515ad7
device: /dev/sda
unit: sectors

/dev/sda1 : start=        2048, size=     1124352, type=7, bootable
/dev/sda2 : start=     1126400, size=   408475648, type=7
/dev/sda3 : start=   409602048, size=  1000001528, type=f
/dev/sda4 : start=  1409605632, size=    40960000, type=83
/dev/sda5 : start=   409602056, size=   409599984, type=7
/dev/sda6 : start=   819204096, size=    78123008, type=83      
/dev/sda7 : start=   897329152, size=     9762816, type=82
/dev/sda8 : start=   907094016, size=   195309568, type=83
/dev/sda9 : start=  1102403592, size=   307199984, type=7
```

Comment: add the output of `sfdisk -d /dev/sda` to your question (replace `/dev/sda` with the disk you want to repartition, if that's not it). Depending on how tight the partition table is, this may not be possible without moving data around.

Comment: added output of sfdisk in question

Answer (score 2):

The partitions are spaced well enough, and you could transform the primary partitition `sda4` into a logical one `sda10`, if you first resize the extended partition `sda3`.

See below for a modified table that you could use with `sfdisk /dev/sda < new_partition`, and for a diff showing the modifications made. After this, you should have a free slot for another primary partition (a new `sda4`).

**However I strongly** advice you to first try it on a dummy file  that you could create with

```
 $ dd if=/dev/null of=/tmp/dummy bs=1 seek=1000G
 $ sfdisk /tmp/dummy < new_partition
```

Then, as root:

```
 # kpartx -a /tmp/dummy
```

The last step will let the kernel attach a loop device (`/dev/loop0` if it isn't already in use) to `/tmp/dummy` and scan all the partitions that you have created on it. Then you could check with partitioning tools like `fdisk` or `gparted` if they're able to parse the partitioning of `/dev/loop0` fine. Only after all that proceed with the

```
# sfdisk /dev/sda < new_partition
```

followed by a reboot.

You should also change any references to `sda4` to `sda10` (and `(hd0,msdos4)` to `(hd0,msdos10)`) in `/etc/fstab` and `/etc/grub.d/*` (the latter followed by an `update-grub`).

By all means, **do not accuse me of anything** if you're hosing your system ;-)

It may be better to wait for another answer, there are probably automated tools that could convert your partition table to GPT or such things, or more friendly partitioning programs that let you do it in a guided way.

**new_partition**:

```
/dev/sda1 : start=        2048, size=     1124352, type=7, bootable
/dev/sda2 : start=     1126400, size=   408475648, type=7
/dev/sda3 : start=   409602048, size=  1040963584, type=f
/dev/sda5 : start=   409602056, size=   409599984, type=7
/dev/sda6 : start=   819204096, size=    78123008, type=83
/dev/sda7 : start=   897329152, size=     9762816, type=82
/dev/sda8 : start=   907094016, size=   195309568, type=83
/dev/sda9 : start=  1102403592, size=   307199984, type=7
/dev/sda10 : start=  1409605632, size=   40960000, type=83
```

**diff**:

```
@@ -1,9 +1,9 @@
 /dev/sda1 : start=        2048, size=     1124352, type=7, bootable
 /dev/sda2 : start=     1126400, size=   408475648, type=7
-/dev/sda3 : start=   409602048, size=  1000001528, type=f
-/dev/sda4 : start=  1409605632, size=    40960000, type=83
+/dev/sda3 : start=   409602048, size=  1040963584, type=f
 /dev/sda5 : start=   409602056, size=   409599984, type=7
 /dev/sda6 : start=   819204096, size=    78123008, type=83
 /dev/sda7 : start=   897329152, size=     9762816, type=82
 /dev/sda8 : start=   907094016, size=   195309568, type=83
 /dev/sda9 : start=  1102403592, size=   307199984, type=7
+/dev/sda10 : start=  1409605632, size=   40960000, type=83
```