# How can I split a monolithic partition into two, one for `/` and one for `/home`?

Tags: partition, gparted, parted

Right now, I have everything in a partition (except EFI system partition).
How can I split the partition into two, one for `/` and one for `/home`?

How would you use `parted` to do that step by step?

How would you use `gparted` to do that step by step?

How would you use LVM to do that step by step? [Stephen suggested so.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/502300/can-parted-move-a-partition-like-gparted#comment926085_502304)

One thing I am not sure of is that I can't just shrink the partition and create a second partition on the space that is freed by shrinking, because that doesn't move `/home` to the new partition.

Thanks.

[image]

```
$ sudo parted -l
[sudo] password for t: 
Model: ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ABF0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB  fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   500GB  500GB  ext4

$ sudo df -h
[sudo] password for t: 
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.7G     0  1.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs           340M  1.4M  338M   1% /run
/dev/sda2       457G  6.7G  428G   2% /
tmpfs           1.7G   27M  1.7G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.7G     0  1.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       511M  6.1M  505M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs           340M   20K  340M   1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs           340M     0  340M   0% /run/user/106
```

Comment: I don't think so. I don't have time to argue with you.

Comment: just move the contents of old `/home` to the new partition after creating the new one. `gparted` cannot do that. And use a Live USB for that.

Comment: Why would resizing be an issue? Your `/home` is not a partition, it's just a normal subdirectory of `/`. Resizing the `/` partition will not affect `/home`, why would it? If you want to use the new partition as your `/home`, that's a different issue but it is still quite simple: just copy the contents of `/home` to the new partition and set the new partition's mountpoint as `/home`. You can easily find dozens of tutorials about this sort of basic partition setup.

Answer (score 4):

- Boot a livecd with gparted available
- Use gparted to resize the root partition and create the new one.
- Mount the partitions somewhere.
- Move the data with mv
- Edit the fstab so the new partition will be mounted on /home
- Reboot back into your regular system

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to use LVM step by step instead? I was suggested to use LVM https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/502300/can-parted-move-a-partition-like-gparted#comment926085_502304

Comment: @Tim please try a google search for "lvm tutorial" and then ask a new question about a specific part of it if you are still having trouble.

Comment: LVM does have it's advantages, but it also has it's downsides. For example as I understand it shrinking a LV requires you to manually coordinate the resizing of the filesystem and the LV.