# How shall I split a partition containing `/` and `/home` into two logical volumes?

Tags: ubuntu, partition, lvm

I have a laptop running Lubuntu 18.04, with a single hard drive as a bootable disk, and two partitions on it: EFI System Partition and a bigger partition contains everything else (e.g. `/` an `/home`).

```
$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ABF0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB  fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   500GB  500GB  ext4
```

I want to separate `/` and `/home` in some way, so that messing up with `/` will have limited interference with `/home`. For example, I am considering to separate them  into  two different logical volumes using LVM, as suggested by Stephen Kill below. But it seems that [I can't mark the bigger partition as a physical volume](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/502424/why-cant-i-create-a-physical-volume), so what shall I do now? (Besides the laptop, I have a Lubuntu bootable flash drive and another laptop also running Lubuntu 18.04).

```
$ sudo lvmdiskscan
  /dev/sda1 [     512.00 MiB] 
  /dev/sda2 [    <465.26 GiB] 
  0 disks
  2 partitions
  0 LVM physical volume whole disks
  0 LVM physical volumes

$ sudo pvcreate /dev/sda2
  Can't open /dev/sda2 exclusively.  Mounted filesystem?
```

If I can afford to reinstall Lubuntu on the laptop, will reinstalling the OS help to separate `/` an `/home` into different logical volumes? How shall I do exactly?

If I don't want to reinstall Lubuntu on the laptop, what shall I do then?

Did telcoM and Stephen Kitt recommended  the same? What are the steps so that  I   can follow their suggestions  respectively?

[telcoM wrote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/501352/how-shall-i-improve-the-current-partitioning-of-my-hard-drive-for-linux-filsyste#comment925310_501410):

> The problem is that you cannot just add LVM to an existing non-LVM
>   partition. You would have to shrink your existing partition as much as
>   you can, then create a new partition to be used as a LVM PV, create
>   the LV(s) you desire into it, copy the data, update your boot
>   configuration and initramfs to be aware of LVM, then boot to the LVM
>   version of the system, and then either repurpose the old non-LVM
>   partition as a second LVM PV on the same disk and add it to the
>   existing VG, or remove it and resize the only LVM PV on the disk.

[Stephen Kitt wrote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/502300/can-parted-move-a-partition-like-gparted#comment926075_502304)

> On bootable disks, I have whatever partitions are needed to boot the
>   system (such as the ESP on EFI systems, or /boot on BIOS or U-boot
>   systems), and one big partition occupying all the available space,
>   which is used as a PV in LVM.
>
> you can have one partition for the ESP, and another partition which
>   you use with LVM: that large partition (/dev/sda2) is a PV, used in a
>   VG, containing however many LVs you want (one for / and one for /home)

Comment: Although correct, telecoMZ's too troublesome, just backup to external storage, then recreate the LVM layer using sda2. So You need a Live CD and external disk for this. Or more simple, backup important personal documents to Google driver sort of thing then re-install

Comment: Or even the simplest, you don't need LVM for your PC, if you want to test LVM, use virtual machine.

Comment: (1) " just backup to external storage, then recreate the LVM layer using sda2. So You need a Live CD and external disk for this." Does this not require reinstalling Lubuntu? Do I need to install LVM to a Live CD first, so that I can run LVM when from the live CD? (2) "Or more simple, backup important personal documents to Google driver sort of thing then re-install". Does this require reinstalling Lubuntu?