# Do the (relative) positions of the partitions matter?

Tags: partition, hard-disk

The layout of my current disk (ST1000LM014) is:

[image]

Do the (relative) positions of the partitions matter?

what are the pros and cons of the following orderings:

```
swap, home, root
swap, root, home
root, swap, home
root, home, swap
home, swap, root
home, root, swap
```

?

Thanks.

Comment: is this what they call a ["spinning rust"](https://www.wired.com/2012/10/linus-torvalds-hard-disks/) disk, or solid-state?

Comment: and, assuming a spinning disk, for answerers to have a chance of a useful opinion, do you expect swap, home, or root to be more or less heavily utilized?

Comment: @JeffSchaller the part number [suggests](https://www.newegg.com/global/uk-en/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822178340) a hybrid 5400 RPM 6Gb/s spinner.

Answer (score 2):

On "spinning rust" disks (HDDs), a very general rule-of-thumb would be that towards the beginning of the disk (= towards the left side in `gparted`) is often somewhat faster than the end (right side).

However, if you really need storage performance on these days, get yourself a SSD drive. The difference in performance between a SSD and a HDD is orders of magnitude more than what you can achieve by hyper-optimizing your HDD's partition arrangement.

---

Relative to the total size of your disk, your swap partition is small enough to have negligible effect to performance. (If you really need your swap to be fast, you are most likely suffering from RAM shortage, and that is best fixed by buying more RAM!)

So, it's essentially a question of whether you prefer (slightly) faster access to the OS files or to the files in your `/home`.

If you often compile software from source code, you might want to have your root partition be in the first 1/4 or so of the disk, as it contains `/usr/include` which can be heavily accessed by the compiler. Of course, if you don't have a shortage of RAM, it will be cached anyway... Another advantage of this positioning is that it might make the system start-up (very) slightly faster.

But if you use your system in a more server-like style, with a database or some specific application (= whatever is in your `/home`) being your main workload and generating a non-trivial amount of disk I/O, then you might want to have that in the faster position, and let the root filesystem take the slowest position.

But the differences in performance you might achieve by rearranging the partitions are probably small enough that you'd need careful benchmarking to detect them.

Comment: Thanks According to your theory, could you point out the pros and cons of the six orderings?