# What are the limitations on where we can move a partition in gparted?

Tags: partition, hard-disk, gparted

**Please leave the two posts open, until you can write a good answer to cover both.**

The layout of my current disk is:

[image]

In gparted, when I select a partition, and click "Partition->resize/move", is it correct that I can only move the partition if there is unallocated region immediately behind or before it? For example, is it correct that I can move sda4 anywhere into the 93G unallocated region, but I can't move sda3 at all?

If yes, does that imply that the relative order between partitions can't be changed?

What is the command which gparted uses to perform partition moving?

Comment: You can get the answer but the knowledge you've got, just do thinking. If you want to move the partition, which part of data you need to write? Based on your knowledge about partition table.

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 I am not sure. Could you explain specifically to my questions? Thanks.

Comment: Remember as less rules as you can, and think as more as you can. I've marked this as duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

`gparted` does indeed only consider moving partitions inside the space currently occupied by the partition and any free space before and after it. So you can’t move `sda3` yet; but you can move `sda4`, and if you do, you’ll be able to move `sda3` using the freed space between `sda4` and `sda3`. (Assuming the other constraints on moving partitions are met: you can’t move a partition containing a mounted file system, and the file system must be clean.)

This does imply that the relative order between partitions can’t be changed. However, `gparted` can copy partitions and delete them, which produces the same end result.

In most cases, `gparted` uses its own implementation to move partitions. For partitions containing ext2/3/4 file systems or Linux swap, it will however use `e2image` (if available) and `mkswap` respectively. The “File System Support” entry in the “View” menu will show you what features are supported given the currently installed tools, and list the tools `gparted` needs:

[image]

Comment: @Tim As your filesystems are supported, go with gparted. Right click on the partition and choose your action. I guess deleting is always possible with gparted as long as the partition table is not corrupted. Other actions depend on the supported fs types and installed tools. Click on "View -> File System Support" for a list of all supported actions (move, copy, shrink, etc.).